# Imported Resource Causes Ambiguous Reference Error

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I have run into an ambiguous reference error when using a component from a package, where a primary project also refers to a shared dependency of that component. I have outlined an example project and a dependency project which illustrates the issue.

My aim is to have a base library of UI components, and a separate project that may subclass those components. I am currently unable to subclass those components, because as soon as I do, there ends up being two compiled versions of it - leading to the ambiguous reference error.

*Dart SDK 0.6.5.0 r25017*

---

### My Package

This is the package that I created and imported into my current project. It defines a single Web Component and has a dependency on `Web UI`.

#### MyPackageComponent.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
    <element name="my-package-component" constructor="MyPackageComponent" extends="span">
        <template>My Package Component</template>
        <script type="application/dart" src="MyPackageComponent.dart"></script>
    </element>
</body></html>
```

#### MyPackageComponent.dart

```dart
import "package:web_ui/web_ui.dart";
class MyPackageComponent extends WebComponent
{
    MyPackageComponent();
}
```

---

### My Project

This is the primary project. It defines a single *derived* Web Component and has dependencies on `My Package` and `Web UI`.

#### MyLocalComponent.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
    <element name="my-local-component" constructor="MyLocalComponent" extends="span">
        <template>My Local Component</template>
        <script type="application/dart" src="MyLocalComponent.dart"></script>
    </element>
</body></html>
```

#### MyLocalComponent.dart

Note that `MyLocalComponent` is subclassed from `MyPackageComponent`.

```dart
import "package:MyPackage/MyPackageComponent.dart";
class MyLocalComponent extends MyPackageComponent
{
    MyLocalComponent();
}
```

#### Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <link rel="import" href="package:MyPackage/MyPackageComponent.html"/>
    <link rel="import" href="MyLocalComponent.html"/>
</head><body>
    <my-local-component></my-local-component>     <!-- REF 1 -->
    <my-package-component></my-package-component> <!-- REF 2 -->
    <!-- Dart scripts etc. -->
</body>
```

---

### Result

Everything runs fine if I use only the local component in `Index.html` (see *REF 1*). When I use the packaged component (see *REF 2*), I run into the following error:

```
Internal error: 'file:[omitted]/MyProject/src/out/Index.html.dart': Error: line [omitted] pos [omitted]: ambiguous reference: 'MyPackageComponent' is defined in library 'file:[omitted]/MyProject/src/out/_from_packages/MyPackage/MyPackageComponent.html.dart' and also in 'package:MyPackage/MyPackageComponent.dart'
  __t.component(new MyPackageComponent()..host = __e0);
                    ^ [omitted]/MyProject/src/out/index.html_bootstrap.dart:0
```

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if this is a bug. It seems highly unlikely that I can not use resources from other packages.

### Investigation

There is an auto-generated folder in the `out` directory named `_from_packages` that seems to be the source of the ambiguous reference. `MyPackageComponent` is defined in there as well as in the `packages` directory.

Seems like the Web UI compiler is generating a class for the imported `MyPackageComponent.dart` (used specifically by the imported component) in addition to the original in `packages/MyPackage/MyPackageComponent.dart` which is referred to elsewhere in `My Project`.

Comment: I have encountered a similar situation a couple of times now. Maybe you could circumvent by naming one of the imports with an as alias.